# stable-baselines3 PPO model loaded but not working

Tags: python, pytorch, openai-gym, stable-baselines, racing

I am trying to make an AI agent for playing OpenAI Gym CarRacing environment and I am having trouble loading saved models. I train them, they work, I save them and load them and suddenly the car doesn't even move. I even tried downloading models from other people and when loaded, the car just doesn't move.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 in VS Code in a Jupyter notebook using
gym==0.21.0, stable-baselines3==1.6.0, python==3.7.0

```
import gym 
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy
import os
```

I make the environment

```
environment_name = "CarRacing-v0"
env = gym.make(environment_name)
```

I create the PPO model and make it learn for a couple thousand timesteps. Now when I evaluate the policy, the car renders as moving.

```
log_path = os.path.join('Training', 'Logs')
model = PPO("CnnPolicy", env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log=log_path)
model.learn(total_timesteps=4000)
evaluate_policy(model, env, n_eval_episodes=1, render=True)
```

I save the model

```
ppo_path = os.path.join('Training', 'Saved Models', 'PPO_Car_Testing')
model.save(ppo_path)
```

now I delete the model and load the saved one and when I evaluate it the car just doesn't move as if it always got action do nothing. I tried models learning for 2k timesteps up to a model which has been learning for 2 million timesteps.

```
del model
model = PPO("CnnPolicy", env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log=log_path)
ppo_path_load = os.path.join('Training', 'Saved Models', 'PPO_2m_Driving_model')
model.load(ppo_path_load, env)
evaluate_policy(model, env, n_eval_episodes=1, render=True)
```

Any ideas why the models load incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like you model didn't load Correctly

you gave the code wrong

```
model = PPO("CnnPolicy", env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log=log_path)
ppo_path_load = os.path.join('Training', 'Saved Models', 'PPO_2m_Driving_model')
model.load(ppo_path_load, env)
```

Change it to as

```
model = PPO("CnnPolicy", env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log=log_path)
ppo_path_load = os.path.join('Training', 'Saved Models', 'PPO_2m_Driving_model')
model = ppo.load(ppo_path_load, env)
```

change `RLALGORITHM` to your Rl-agorithm such as PPO or A2C, etc

```
model = RLALGORITHM.load(ppo_path_load, env)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be solved using PPO.load() instead of model.load(). Not sure why tho.

Here is the correct code for loading the model

```
del model
ppo_path_load = os.path.join('Training', 'Saved Models', 'PPO_2m_Driving_model')
model = PPO.load(ppo_path_load)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the docstring of the `load` method, you will read:

> Load the model from a zip-file.
> Warning: `load` re-creates the model from scratch, it does not update it in-place!
> For an in-place load use `set_parameters` instead.

Therefore, the solution to your problem may be:

```
model = model.load(ppo_path_load, env)
```

This behavior confused me as well. Maybe we can report back to the developers.